# text gets embedded as link in table

Tags: html, ruby

```
def create_email_body_ganglia(array,title,heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4)
  custom_rows =""
  array.each_slice(4) do |row|
  custom_rows << "<tr><td>#{row[0]}</td><td>#{row[1]}</td><td>#{row[2]}</td><td>#{row[3]}</td></tr>"
  end
message = <<MESSAGE_END
```

I trying to form html tables dynamically, by inserting elements in `<td>` from an array in ruby code and then emailing it .
But the email I get shows html content as links because the elements I insert are of the form example.com.

Can I just make them look as text?

Comment: many e-mail clients automatically make strings like "xyz.com" hyperlink format, e.g. Gmail (not all though). I too have had this problem. I am not sure of a way around this -- you may want to add some CSS style to the `<td>`'s. This is a tough one man :\

Comment: @khanahk Thanks .. ya it gets auto converted to strings .. bad

Answer (score 0):

You can change the look of links by using the below script lines.

```
a:link {text-decoration: none; color: black;}               
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: black;}               
a:active {text-decoration: none; color: black;}             
a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
```

These not only work in eamils but for any linked text within a webpage.